# [python]Is there any shortcut to make a 3d matrix?

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I wanna make a 3d matrix like this one.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
y = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
z = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)
u = np.zeros((11, 11, 11))
for i in range(len(x)):
    for j in range(len(y)):
        for k in range(len(z)):
            u[i, j, k] = np.min((x[i], y[j], z[k]))
```

The result is as follow.

```
array([[[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    ..., 
    [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.]],

   [[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
    [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
    ..., 
    [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
    [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
    [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.]],

   [[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
    [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   2.,   2.,   2.],
    ..., 
    [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   2.,   2.,   2.],
    [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   2.,   2.,   2.],
    [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   2.,   2.,   2.]],

   ..., 

   [[  0.,   0.,   0., ...,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [  0.,   1.,   1., ...,   1.,   1.,   1.],
    [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   2.,   2.,   2.],
    ..., 
    [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   8.,   8.,   8.],
    [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   8.,   9.,   9.],
    [  0.,   1.,   2., ...,   8.,   9.,  10.]]])
```

But the above code is very time consuming.
Could you recommend any other way to make the matrix shortly.
It would be better to be coded with numpy module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.minimum()` and broadcasting for this:

```
u2 = np.minimum(np.minimum(x[:, None, None], y[None, :, None]), z[None, None, :])
numpy.allclose(u, u2)  # True
```